# Simple database creation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I never worked with databases before so i find them pretty difficult to master.

Is there a way i can design a database without writing actual SQL Code? Then export it into a SQLServer 2008 data base ( http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/competitor-compare.aspx ) database.

Comment: Where did you get a `MYSQL Server 2008`? It's the first time I hear about it.

Comment: Cool. I had the right feeling about editing tags for this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server (and not MySQL), you can use SQL Server Management Studio to create the database, and it has a visual designer to create the tables and design the database.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. There are tools which writes a query for you, for example [phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net)

Comment: I am looking into creating a database with connections

Answer (score 1):

Navicat is a great tool. I would check it out.

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com)

Answer (score 1):

SequelPro http://www.sequelpro.com/ for mac is very good for creating databases without having to know any sql code.

Similarly Navicat http://www.navicat.com/ is very good too, and cross platform.

I would suggest, if you have an interest in programming, learning how to work with mysql and databases anyway. Its a useful skill to have, and one which isn't exactly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Another: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (standalone app) - server has to be configured to accept remote connections. The new version also unify the functionality of previously known products - MySQL Administrator and MySQL Query Browser. However, there is no free tool, which is like SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Err... There is no such product as "MySQL Server 2008". There are "Microsoft SQL Server 2008" and "MySQL Server". An answer to your question depends on what exact database you're using. For MySQL you can use phpmyadmin, as [@Martin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912449/625594). For SQL Server 2008 you may achieve similar results by using [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593).